# How do you install jenkins within a certain directory?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, system

How do you install jenkins such that it will install within `C:\Users\Public`
and not `C:\Users\id`

At the moment I have the jenkins jar file, and have a bat file that will start up jenkins.

bat file

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=portnum
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set an Env variable JENKINS_HOME pointing to the directory you wish to install Jenkins on
2. Execute `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=portnum` post that

Refer this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

Although its recommended to install Jenkins on a free drive. I would install it on a free D drive and have JENKINS_HOME as "D:\Jenkins"

Comment: unsure what you mean by posting. How do you go about doing that.

Comment: @user I guess this "_post_" is meant to mean [_after_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/post#Etymology_4).

Comment: Yes, It means after you set the Env variable you execute this command